# Access to multiple virtual machines at once or other alternative?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-media-center

I have a Windows 7 computer that acts as a media center and a workstation where I work. Therefore, it needs to be accessed simultaneously by multiple users.

Currently, when someone wants to change something on the media center they have to select media center which allows the remote to work, and when they're done the regular user can switch back to their applications and continue working. It's becoming quite a pain. Short of buying another computer, what are my options? I haven't checked hardware yet but if the machine can run VMware's ESXi could I have one VM run media center and one run the workstation, but have both going at the same time? I'm not sure how that works.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using something like VirtualBox ([www.virtualbox.org](http://www.virtualbox.org)) since it's free and you do not need to change anything with your Operating System.

Comment: Is that similar to VMWare's player? If it is, then it will not work since you still have to "select" which window you will be working in. Unless I'm missing something or there's a different way of setting it up.

Comment: VirtualBox allows you to configure multiple monitors. Can you give a bit more of a layout? There may be a way to set the second monitor to the VM's second monitor.